# SQLSERVER - How to list Procs created by a particular user?

Tags: sql-server, procedure

**SQLSERVER** 
How to list Procs created by a particular user?

I would like to find all procedures created by my user. It may be for a short time.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to find a SP created or modified by user in SQL Server. though all the User created SP are listed separately than system SP in SQL Sever Management Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below. Hopefully it will help.

```
    DECLARE @filename VARCHAR(255) 
    SELECT @FileName = SUBSTRING(path, 0, LEN(path)-CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(path))+1) 
    + '\Log.trc'  
    FROM sys.traces   
     WHERE is_default = 1;  

    SELECT gt.HostName, 
    gt.ApplicationName, 
    gt.NTUserName, 
    gt.NTDomainName, 
    gt.LoginName, 
    gt.SPID, 
    gt.EventClass, 
    te.Name AS EventName,
    gt.EventSubClass,      
    gt.TEXTData, 
    gt.StartTime, 
    gt.EndTime, 
    gt.ObjectName, 
    gt.DatabaseName, 
    gt.FileName, 
    gt.IsSystem
    FROM [fn_trace_gettable](@filename, DEFAULT) gt 
    JOIN sys.trace_events te ON gt.EventClass = te.trace_event_id 
    WHERE EventClass in (164) 
    ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
```

SRC - https://serverfault.com/questions/258111/finding-out-who-has-modified-a-stored-procedure-on-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Recent schema changes are available via the Schema Changes History standard report, which uses the default trace as the source. This report can be viewed by right-clicking on the database in SSMS object explorer and selecting Reports-->Standard Reports-->Schema Changes History.

Comment: >>>I would like to find **all** procedures<<< The default trace recycles very quickly, it's hard to find out events older than 5 days even if search for them in all trace files, so it's definitely impossible use it to find ALL the procs

Comment: @sepupic, the retention depends on the activity. The question said " It may be for a short time".